# Superscript, bold and colour in y.axis.title using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem or there is a conflict using

```
ylab(expression(paste(log~Biovolume~µm^3~L^-1)))+
opts(axis.title.y=theme_text(size=16,face="bold",
colour="black",angle=90,vjust=4.3))
```

at the same time. When I use each command separately it works fine, but together, the x-axis disappears without any error message. Unfortunately, I need both commands to express the mathematical part (`ylab(expression(paste(.....))`) and the size and colour of the y-axis title with the `opts(....)` command. I searched now in different fora to find a solution. My idea was to put the size, colour and other properties of the y-axis.title in the `ylab()` command, but I didn't succeed. So, perhaps you have any ideas or solution

```
ggplot(R28meansd, aes(treat, meanbiov, shape=factor(disp))) + 
    geom_point(size=5,position=pd) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=meanbiov-sdbiov,ymax=meanbiov+sdbiov), 
                  colour="black",width=.1,position=pd,size=.7) 
    opts(aspect.ratio=1.4) + 
    theme_bw() + 
    opts(axis.title.y=theme_text(size=16, face="bold",
         colour="black",angle=90,vjust=4.3)) +
    ylab(expression(paste(log~(Biovolume~µm^3~L^-1))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Without a reproducible dataset, I wasn't able to test you exact conditions. However, you can achieve bold typeface in the y-axis with a statement within `expression()`, which seems to override ggplot's `face` parameter. GGplot's `angle`, `vjust`, `size`, and color parameters seem to persist.

```
ylab(expression(bold(paste(log~(Biovolume~µm^3~L^-1)))))+
```